# Can boats move through sea monsters in Survival: Escape from Atlantis?

Tags: escape-from-atlantis

This should be a common sense that you can't move boat through when it is blocked by sea serpent or whale, but I don't see the rule include this situation.

Can a boat move pass through a tile that is occupied by a sea serpent or whale safely? The boat does not stop on the occupied tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boat is destroyed if it's occupied.

> If you move a Ship containing one or more Explorers into a sea space containing a Sea Serpent or a Whale, the Ship is immediately removed from the game, it's passengers become Swimmers (don't forget that if the sea space contains a Shark or Sea Serpent, these Swimmers are immediately removed from the game).

A similar rules exists for Swimmers.

> If you move a Swimmer into a sea space containing a Sea Serpent or a Shark, the Swimmer is immediately removed from the game. Consequently, Swimmers cannot cross that kind of sea spaces.

Comment: *Swimmers cannot cross that kind of sea spaces.* This is what I'm looking for. By this rule, then Move Boat and Move Swimmer (dolphin) also can't be used to cross occupied tile?

Comment: Already answered. If they enter the square, they get affected by the creatures within.

Answer (score 0):

An **occupied** boat cannot move through a whale or sea serpent per the following rule (from 30th anniversary edition).

> If you move a Ship containing one or more Explorers into a sea
>   space containing a Sea Serpent or a Whale, the Ship is immediately removed from the game, its passengers becoming Swimmers
>   (don’t forget that if the sea space contains a Shark or Sea Serpent,
>   these Swimmers are immediately removed from the game).

**However, you may move empty ships per the following rule.  These ships can move freely through whales and sea serpents.**

> When a Ship is empty, any player
>   can move it from one sea space
>   to another, as desired (at the cost
>   of one movement per space).